# Disable iSight Indicator LED on El Capitan

Tags: macos, video, webcam

I use a lot my camera and sometimes I need to do a lot of meetings. I don't like to let people around see that I'm in a video call.

Do you know how to disable the indicator light to always be green when the camera is on?
I'm using a Macbook Air mid-2012 with OS X 10.11 El Capitan. If need, I can disable temporary the security from El Capitan.

Thanks,

Comment: IIRC, you need to hack into the camera device driver to achieve that. I'm pretty sure it has been done by some security researchers, but I don't know if the code to do so has been made public.

Comment: Here is an article about it. It seems you need to hack into the camera device drivers. https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity14/sec14-paper-brocker.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would use a small piece of black tape. If you get the right kind it will be hard to spot and since its always there it won't give you away.

Not the modern software approach but it works.

Comment: I wanted something not visible by people like a black tape :/

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is use a temporary black marker to paint over the led. It will hide like 95% of the led intensity. Enough for what you want and easy to remove with one finger. You can also put transparent tape over the led and then paint with the marker over the tape to reduce to almost 100% the intensity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.ifixit.com and locate a disassembly guide for your Mac. Disassemble the Mac and clip the wires leading to the LED (or remove it completely). Reassemble the Mac. Voila!

Note: I have not tried this. Proceed at your own risk.